# require_once fails to include a file

Tags: php, require-once

I have a script which uses `require_once`, but it fails to actually include the file. I have ran a check and the code agrees that the file is in the right place, using the right paths. Do I need to configure anything extra? Is there a problem with my code?

```
if (is_file('lib/stripe/Stripe.php')){
    echo "Found file";
    require_once 'lib/stripe/Stripe.php';
    echo "Hello World";
}

else{
    echo "Failed to find file";
}
```

"Found file" is successfully returned, but "Hello World" isn't.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? If the required file throws an error `require_once` will fail.

Comment: It's worth always using full paths where applicable too.

Comment: or at least `__DIR__` constants.

Comment: @jim turns out that curl wasn't installed on my server (had been testing locally before moving it to a live server). Error logs are a developers best friend :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error log showed that curl wasn't installed.